# Are create-react-app files visible on client side?

Tags: express, axios, create-react-app

I'm currently experimenting with react and express and I wanted to know if react files are hidden, what m trying to do right now is encrypting api responses server side then decrypting it in the frontend, but having the key visible to everyone makes the entire thing useless

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your React application, your entire source code is visible to everyone from the sources tab of the dev tools.

This is not an issue with the `create-react-app` but all of the source code is added because of the source map which helps to easily identify the source of the bug that will occur on the live site in the future.

**There is an easy way to fix it :**

Create a file with the name **.env** in your project folder with the below code inside it :

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Or add this in `package.json` file  :

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

Now, when you run `/yarn`   command from the terminal, It will generate a
 folder with minified files without a source map that you can deploy to the production.

Hope you find my answer helpful !